# mongoDB - db.collection.remove by _id just outputs

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to remove a record from my database.

When I run this query in the console I only get `...` as output:

```
db.customers.remove({_id: ObjectId("573318f4336f7de600c419a3"}, true)
```

and when I query the database I can see the record is still there:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("573318f4336f7de600c419a3"),
    "last_name" : "Johnson",
    "gender" : "female",
    "age" : 30,
    "birthdate" : ISODate("1989-09-09T22:00:00Z")
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the problem, there was no closing bracket:

The correct code

```
db.customers.remove({_id: ObjectId("573318f4336f7de600c419a3")}, true)
```

Comment: The 3 dots `...` ever indicate that the statement is incomplete :)